# Fastapi python code execution speed impacted by deployment with uvicorn vs gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I wrote an fastapi app. And now I am thinking about deploying it however I seem to get strange unexpected performance issues that seem to depend on wether I use uvicorn vs gunicorn. In particular all code (even standard library pure python code) seems to get slower if I use gunicorn. For performance debugging I wrote a small app that demonstrates this:

```
import asyncio, time
from fastapi import FastAPI, Path
from datetime import datetime

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/delay/{delay1}/{delay2}")
async def get_delay(
    delay1: float = Path(..., title="Nonblocking time taken to respond"),
    delay2: float = Path(..., title="Blocking time taken to respond"),
):
    total_start_time = datetime.now()
    times = []
    for i in range(100):
        start_time = datetime.now()
        await asyncio.sleep(delay1)
        time.sleep(delay2)
        times.append(str(datetime.now()-start_time))
    return {"delays":[delay1,delay2],"total_time_taken":str(datetime.now()-total_start_time),"times":times}
```

Running the fastapi appi with:

```
gunicorn api.performance_test:app -b localhost:8001 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 1
```

The resonse body of a get to `http://localhost:8001/delay/0.0/0.0` is consistently something like:

```
{
  "delays": [
    0.0,
    0.0
  ],
  "total_time_taken": "0:00:00.057946",
  "times": [
    "0:00:00.000323",
    ...smilar values omitted for brevity...
    "0:00:00.000274"
  ]
}
```

However using:

```
uvicorn api.performance_test:app --port 8001
```

I consitently get timings like these

```
{
  "delays": [
    0.0,
    0.0
  ],
  "total_time_taken": "0:00:00.002630",
  "times": [
    "0:00:00.000037",
    ...snip...
    "0:00:00.000020"
  ]
}
```

The difference becomes even more prounced when I uncomment the `await asyncio.sleep(delay1)` statement.

So I am wondering what gunicorn/uvicorn do to the python/fastapi runtime to create this factor 10 difference in the speed of code execution.

For what is is worth I performed these tests using Python 3.8.2 on OS X 11.2.3 with an intel I7 processor.

And these are the relevant parts of my `pip freeze` output

```
fastapi==0.65.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
uvicorn==0.13.4
```

Answer (score 13):

### I can't reproduce your results.

My environment:
ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows 10

relevant parts of my `pip freeze` output:

```
fastapi==0.65.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
uvicorn==0.14.0
```

---

I modified code a little:

```py
import asyncio, time
from fastapi import FastAPI, Path
from datetime import datetime
import statistics

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/delay/{delay1}/{delay2}")
async def get_delay(
    delay1: float = Path(..., title="Nonblocking time taken to respond"),
    delay2: float = Path(..., title="Blocking time taken to respond"),
):
    total_start_time = datetime.now()
    times = []
    for i in range(100):
        start_time = datetime.now()
        await asyncio.sleep(delay1)
        time.sleep(delay2)
        time_delta= (datetime.now()-start_time).microseconds
        times.append(time_delta)

    times_average = statistics.mean(times)

    return {"delays":[delay1,delay2],"total_time_taken":(datetime.now()-total_start_time).microseconds,"times_avarage":times_average,"times":times}
```

Apart from first loading of website, my results for both methods are nearly the same.

Times are between `0:00:00.000530` and `0:00:00.000620` most of the time for both methods.

First attempt for each takes longer: around `0:00:00.003000`.
However after I restarted Windows and tried those tests again I noticed I no longer have increased times on first requests after server startup (I think it is thanks to a lot of free RAM after restart)

---

Examples of not-first runs (3 attempts):

```py
# `uvicorn performance_test:app --port 8083`

{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":553,"times_avarage":4.4,"times":[15,7,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":575,"times_avarage":4.61,"times":[15,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":548,"times_avarage":4.31,"times":[14,6,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4]}


# `gunicorn performance_test:app -b localhost:8084 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 1`

{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":551,"times_avarage":4.34,"times":[13,6,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":558,"times_avarage":4.48,"times":[14,7,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,5,4]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":550,"times_avarage":4.34,"times":[15,6,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,5,5,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4]}
```

---

Examples of not-first runs with commented `await asyncio.sleep(delay1)` (3 attempts):

```py
# `uvicorn performance_test:app --port 8083`

{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":159,"times_avarage":0.6,"times":[3,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":162,"times_avarage":0.49,"times":[3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":156,"times_avarage":0.61,"times":[3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]}


# `gunicorn performance_test:app -b localhost:8084 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 1`

{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":159,"times_avarage":0.59,"times":[2,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":165,"times_avarage":0.62,"times":[3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]}
{"delays":[0.0,0.0],"total_time_taken":164,"times_avarage":0.54,"times":[2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]}
```

I made a Python script to benchmark those times more precisely:

```py
import statistics
import requests
from time import sleep

number_of_tests=1000

sites_to_test=[
    {
        'name':'only uvicorn    ',
        'url':'http://127.0.0.1:8083/delay/0.0/0.0'
    },
    {
        'name':'gunicorn+uvicorn',
        'url':'http://127.0.0.1:8084/delay/0.0/0.0'
    }]


for test in sites_to_test:

    total_time_taken_list=[]
    times_avarage_list=[]

    requests.get(test['url']) # first request may be slower, so better to not measure it

    for a in range(number_of_tests):
        r = requests.get(test['url'])
        json= r.json()

        total_time_taken_list.append(json['total_time_taken'])
        times_avarage_list.append(json['times_avarage'])
        # sleep(1) # results are slightly different with sleep between requests

    total_time_taken_avarage=statistics.mean(total_time_taken_list)
    times_avarage_avarage=statistics.mean(times_avarage_list)

    print({'name':test['name'], 'number_of_tests':number_of_tests, 'total_time_taken_avarage':total_time_taken_avarage, 'times_avarage_avarage':times_avarage_avarage})
```

Results:

```
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 586.5985, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.820865}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 571.8415, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.719035}
```

Results with commented `await asyncio.sleep(delay1)`

```
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 151.301, 'times_avarage_avarage': 0.602495}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 144.4655, 'times_avarage_avarage': 0.59196}
```

I also made another version of above script which changes urls every 1 request (it gives slightly higher times):

```py
import statistics
import requests
from time import sleep

number_of_tests=1000

sites_to_test=[
    {
        'name':'only uvicorn    ',
        'url':'http://127.0.0.1:8083/delay/0.0/0.0',
        'total_time_taken_list':[],
        'times_avarage_list':[]
    },
    {
        'name':'gunicorn+uvicorn',
        'url':'http://127.0.0.1:8084/delay/0.0/0.0',
        'total_time_taken_list':[],
        'times_avarage_list':[]
    }]


for test in sites_to_test:
    requests.get(test['url']) # first request may be slower, so better to not measure it

for a in range(number_of_tests):

    for test in sites_to_test:
        r = requests.get(test['url'])
        json= r.json()

        test['total_time_taken_list'].append(json['total_time_taken'])
        test['times_avarage_list'].append(json['times_avarage'])
        # sleep(1) # results are slightly different with sleep between requests


for test in sites_to_test:
    total_time_taken_avarage=statistics.mean(test['total_time_taken_list'])
    times_avarage_avarage=statistics.mean(test['times_avarage_list'])

    print({'name':test['name'], 'number_of_tests':number_of_tests, 'total_time_taken_avarage':total_time_taken_avarage, 'times_avarage_avarage':times_avarage_avarage})
```

Results:

```
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 589.4315, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.789385}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 589.0915, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.761095}
```

Results with commented `await asyncio.sleep(delay1)`

```
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 152.8365, 'times_avarage_avarage': 0.59173}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 2000, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 154.4525, 'times_avarage_avarage': 0.59768}
```

This answer should help you debug your results better.

I think it may help to investigate your results if you share more details about your OS / machine.

Also please restart your computer/server, it may have impact.

---

**Update 1:**

I see that I used newer version of uvicorn `0.14.0` than stated in question `0.13.4`.
I also tested with older version `0.13.4` but results are similar, I still can't reproduce your results.

---

**Update 2:**

I run some more benchmarks and I noticed something interesting:

##### with uvloop in requirements.txt:

whole requirements.txt:

```
uvicorn==0.14.0
fastapi==0.65.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
uvloop==0.15.2
```

Results:

```py
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 500, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 362.038, 'times_avarage_avarage': 2.54142}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 500, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 366.814, 'times_avarage_avarage': 2.56766}
```

##### without uvloop in requirements.txt:

whole requirements.txt:

```
uvicorn==0.14.0
fastapi==0.65.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Results:

```py
{'name': 'only uvicorn    ', 'number_of_tests': 500, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 595.578, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.83828}
{'name': 'gunicorn+uvicorn', 'number_of_tests': 500, 'total_time_taken_avarage': 584.64, 'times_avarage_avarage': 4.7155}
```

---

**Update 3:**

I was using only `Python 3.9.5` in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive testing! My OS/Machine was already hidden somewhere in my long question. I performed these tests using Python 3.8.2 on OS X 11.2.3 with an intel I7 processor. I will see if I can also run some tests on a plain Ubuntu machine. Also thanks for pointing out that just installing uvloop gives a significant performance boost!

Comment: @M.D. Ok, I missed it. I was using only Python 3.9.5 in this answer, so it was also different version than yours. My CPU is Ryzen 3700x.

Comment: so, will gunicorn with uvicorn+uvloop make thigs better than plain uvicorn and uvicorn+uvloop?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Yes, because uvicorn can't use multiple CPU cores itself. You need to combine it with gunicorn to be able to use all CPU cores available. Gunicorn will act then as a process manager, not as a web server. Uvicorn was designed to not contain process manager itself and instead use one from Gunicorn. You can read more in uvicorn documentation: https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-with-gunicorn

Comment: thanks for the reply. in that case, i wouldn't need need gunicorn if i have to run uvicorn in a single core machine, yes? and i run multiple containers, each with a single unicorn process in a single core machine and use k8s's scaling and management? and not using gunicorn also won't result in any performance degradation?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Yes, I think in your case you can use just Uvicorn. But using gunicorn with single uvicorn worker may still give you some additional functionalities, e.g.: 
"Gunicorn gives you some more advanced options wrt. signal handling and restarts, but most users probably don't actually need that." (source: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/517#issuecomment-564090865 )
BTW From what I see uvicorn probably at some point will deprecate gunicorn in favour of its own process manager.

Comment: Note that adding `uvicorn[standard]` to your `requirements.txt` will automatically install `uvloop` as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is due to the underlying web server you use.

An analogy can be: `two cars, same brand, same options, just a different engine, what's the difference?`

Web servers are not exactly like a car, but I guess you get the point I'm trying to make.

Basically, `gunicorn` is a `synchronous` web server, while `uvicorn` is an `asynchronous` web server. Since you're using `fastapi` and `await` keywords I guess that you already know what `asyncio`/`asynchornous programming` is.

I don't know the code differences, so take my answer with a grain of salt, but `uvicorn` is more performant because of the `asynchronous` part. My guess for the timing difference, is that if you use an `async` web server, it is already configured on startup for handling `async` functions, while if you use a `sync` web server, it isn't and there is some kind of overhead in order to abstract that part.

It's not a proper answer, but it gives you a hint on where the difference could lie.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I appreciate for giving me a bit of context. And I would get where the timing difference is coming from if I was doing the timing outside the function call, in an external stres testing tool for example. However all the timing code is inside the get_delay code. And even if I put the body of the get_delay function in a separate synchronous function (without  the asyncio.sleep of course cause it is now in a function where await is illegal) and just have `async def get_delay(delay1, delay2): return sync_function_call(delay1, delay2)`, I get similar timing differences.

Comment: So for some reason it seems that when running under guvicorn all things all cpu bound python code will get slower.  And the same goes for cpu bound code in imported python packages. The only explanation I can think of is that maybe gunicorn is installing some hooks that git triggered by some very common event in pure python code execution.

Comment: These are two engines that are optimized for different things. `gunicorn` was created with `synchronous` code in mind, while `uvicorn` was created with `asynchronous` code in mind. Also, there's a remote possibility that `uvicorn` exposes `uvloop`'s event-loop instead of the buit-in `asyncio` event-loop, where the former is much faster than the latter. Though, I'm not sure about this, but benchmarks provide good results https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop

Comment: My suggestion is for you to not bother too much about performances, unless they are a hard constraint for your project.  If `ASGI` servers are available, use one of them (it makes sense, since you're using an `ASGI` framework), otherwise use a `WGSI` like `gunicorn`. The former is optimized for running the `asynchronous` functions in `fastapi`, the latter isn't

Answer (score 0):

As `fastapi` is an `ASGI` framework so it will provide better performance with `ASGI` server like `uvicorn` or `hypercorn`. `WSGI` sever like `gunicorn` would not able provide performance like `uvicorn`. `ASGI` servers are optimized for  `asynchronous` functions. The official documents of `fastapi` also encourage to use of the `ASGI` servers like `uvicorn` or `hypercorn`.

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#installation

Comment: Take into account that `gunicorn` can be used with `uvicorn` to take advantage of multiple cores / CPUs

Comment: `gunicorn` can be used for serving asgi, and is one of the recommended ways of serving `uvicorn`. https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#gunicorn